# How to convert arrays to vectors using STL

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

This code is a linear search program using arrays. Out of curiosity, I was wondering how this code could be rewritten using STL vectors in place of arrays but still have the same output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int linearSearch(T list[], int key, int arraySize)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    if (key == list[i])
      return i;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int intArray[] =
  {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 15, 23, 31
  };
  cout << "linearSearch(intArray, 3, 8) is " << linearSearch(intArray, 3, 8) << endl;
  cout << "linearSearch(intArray, 10, 8) is " << linearSearch(intArray, 10, 8) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All you have to change is `T list[]` to `const std::vector<T> &` and `int intArray[]` to `std::vector<int> intArray`.

Comment: And you don't have to pass around the size of your list any more.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `linearSearch` function too, you can simply use `std::find`

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
int linearSearch(const vector<T> &list, const T &key)
{
    auto itr = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), key);

    if (itr != list.end())
        return std::distance(list.begin(), itr);
    else
        return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int intArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 15, 23, 31};

    std::vector<int> vec(intArray, intArray + 8);

    int i = linearSearch(vec, 15);
}
```

*Note: C++11 is enabled*

Comment: I think they mean, "using `std::vectors` in the code, instead of raw arrays", not actually converting.

Comment: @Xymostech Then they have to write "using `std::vectors` in the code, instead of raw arrays" and not "converting".

Comment: @H2CO3 In their question, they say "I was wondering how this code could be rewritten using STL vectors in place of arrays". Perhaps their title is just not informative.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by changing your parameter type and in main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int linearSearch(vector<T> list, int key)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
   {
      if (key == list[i])
        return i;
   }

   return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int intArray[] =
  {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 15, 23, 31
   };
   vector<int> list(intArray, intArray+8);

   cout << "linearSearch(list, 3,) is " << linearSearch(list, 3) << endl;
   cout << "linearSearch(list, 10) is " << linearSearch(list, 10) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass the size of the vector, just use `list.size()`

Comment: @Xymostech I agree. the reason I did that is that I want to make minimal change on the code. Code updated, thanks!

Comment: It would be much more efficient to accept the vector by a reference to const instead of by value.

Answer (score 1):

This could work (it is based on the STL implementation):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename ForwardIter, typename Type>
int linearSearch(ForwardIter beg, ForwardIter end, Type key )
{
  int i = 0;
  for (;beg != end; ++beg)
  {
    if (key == *beg)
      return i;
    i++;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  vector< int > vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  cout << "linearSearch 1 is " << linearSearch(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 4) << endl;
  cout << "linearSearch 2 is " << linearSearch(vec.begin()+2, vec.end(), 1) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** it can also work for, `std::list` and `std::deque`. I think it will produce correct results even in a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

With as few changes as possible you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Using const std::vector<T> & to prevent making a copy of the container
template <typename T>
int linearSearch(const std::vector<T> &list, int key)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
    if (key == list[i])
      return i;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> arr = { 1 ,2, 3, 4, 8, 15, 23, 31 } ;

  cout << "linearSearch(intArray, 3) is " << linearSearch(arr, 3) << endl;
  cout << "linearSearch(intArray, 10) is " << linearSearch(arr, 10) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I would recommend not using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: In order to archive what you obviously intended, you must to make the second parameter of your `linearSearch` function to be of type `T`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 template <typename T>
 int linearSearch(T list, int key)
```

Changing the two first lines of your code as above, as well as replacing `arraySize` with `list.size()` should suffice for any kind of container supporting `operator []` (including vectors), and indices as consecutive `int`.

Note that while your template tries to abstract the content of the array as the typename `T`, it implicitely assumes it is `int` in the type of `key`.  A more generic implementation would be:

```
template <typename T>
int linearSearch(T list, typename T::value_type key)
```

Another issue in this solution is the passing mode of `list`. We can overcome this issue by converting it to a reference like so:

```
// includes ...
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
int linearSearch(add_lvalue_reference<T> list, typename T::value_type key){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (key == list[i])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following example that uses STL linear search algorithm. And see possible implementations of std::find and an example of usage it for a vector here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find
It would give you a good answer on your question.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() {

    std::vector<int> intsCollection {1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 15, 23, 31};
        
    std::vector<int>::iterator val1 = std::find(intsCollection.begin(), intsCollection.end(), 3);
    int pos1 = (val1 != intsCollection.end()) ? (val1 - intsCollection.begin()) : -1;
    
    std::vector<int>::iterator val2 = std::find(intsCollection.begin(), intsCollection.end(), 10);
    int pos2 = (val2 != intsCollection.end()) ? (val2 - intsCollection.begin()) : -1;
        
    std::cout << "linearSearch(intsCollection, 3, 8) is " << pos1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "linearSearch(intsCollection, 10, 8) is " << pos2 << std::endl;

}
```